# Print text files as PDFs without manual saving

Tags: python

I need to convert large amount of text files to PDF. Problem with them is, that they use some old encoding and formatting, so it is not possible to use some PDF creating or converting packages without corrupting them, like FPDF. Only thing that works is print to pdf, but to do that I need to choose name and save location every time.
Is there a way to choose save location of PDFs automatically or not?

Code I tried to work with:

```
from win32 import win32print as wp
from win32 import win32api

wp.SetDefaultPrinter('Microsoft Print to PDF')
win32api.ShellExecute(0, 'print', 'test.txt', None, '.', 0)
```

I also tried writing a script in Powershell, but I couldn't find a way to save them.

Here is a sample of the file : https://transfer.sh/knuSnM/test.TXT

Comment: I am not using any specific app, just plain print in win10, that allows me to change txt to pdf uncorrupted. Unfortunetly, this is one of the cases, when they send you something to work with, and you have no idea what it is. I tried quite a lot of encode decode options on several encodings, bu to no success. Also I provided a sample as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set **default** layout in printer settings, can be done via a program command but so much simpler via normal windows GUI, chose between portrait and landscape. your sample is narrow so I chose portrait.

[image]

At a standard console command line in a working folder with your test file run

```
write /pt Test.txt "Microsoft Print to PDF" "Microsoft Print to PDF" test.pdf
```

The result should be acceptable Ansi2PDF conversion.

[image]

Now you can run in a python shell with variable filenames, or simpler use a shortcut for files or for a folder use one line console command along the lines of

```
for /f %a in ('dir /b *.txt') do write /pt "%~dpna.txt" "Microsoft Print to PDF" "Microsoft Print to PDF" "%~dpna.pdf"
```

***However that is not robust*** as tested on my odd test files there are some fails but you get the drift of what's needed in python.
Personally I use a more complex batch file see https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/raw/master/AppNotes/Doc2PDF.cmd